# How do i show wordpress attachments from current post?

Tags: post-thumbnails, attachments

So with my blog i have a photo attachment page but it only shows to photo's at a time, and those two photo's are used as the navigation and i hate that.

I want the attachment page to show all the photo's that goes along with the rest of that set.

Here is the current code

```
        <div id="nav-images" class="navigation clearfix">
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_image_link() ?></div>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_image_link() ?></div>
```

How do i change that to show all the post attachments?

Answer (score 4):

Your code and description seem to refer to the *previous/next attachment **navigation***. That code is intended to display *previous/next attachment navigation*, and that's exactly what it's doing.

If you want to display all attachments:

1. Within the Post Content, use [the `[gallery]` shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode)
2. Programmatically, in the template file, use e.g. [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), combined with e.g. [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image):

   ```
   <?php
   global $post;
   $attachment_images = get_posts(
       'post_type' => 'attachment',
       'post_parent' => $post->post_parent,
       'post_mime_type' => 'image'
   );
   // Output images
   ?>
   <ul>
   <?php
   foreach ( $attachment_images as $attachment_image ) {
       // Output images here. Note that get_posts()
       // returns an array of OBJECTS, so the ID
       // would be $attachment_image->ID
       echo '<li>' . wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_image->ID, 'thumbnail' ) . '</li>';
   }
   ?>
   </ul>
   ```

Comment: Hi, That post does code does not work, is there another one

Comment: You've not provided *nearly* enough information for me to answer your question any more accurately. I don't know what exactly you tried, where you put the code, or what the output was.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Chip, Unfortunately that didn't work, but I finally found it after hours and hours of searching.

First you have to add the below code to the functions.php file

```
function show_all_thumbs() {
    global $post;
    $post = get_post($post);
    /* image code */
    $images =& get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&output=ARRAY_N&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC&post_parent='.$post->post_parent);
    if($images){
        foreach( $images as $imageID => $imagePost ){
            unset($the_b_img);
            $the_b_img = wp_get_attachment_image($imageID, 'thumbnail', false);
            $thumblist .= '<a href="'.get_attachment_link($imageID).'">'.$the_b_img.'</a>';
        }
    }
    return $thumblist;
}
```

and then add the below code to where you want the thumbnails to show.

```
<?php echo show_all_thumbs();?>
```

Sorry I don't know how to put the whole code in the box so i had to jam toegether every line :(

Comment: I'm glad you found a working solution, but you're doing almost *exactly* what I suggested. :)